# python3 execute script without dependency

Tags: python-3.x, pip

My python3 script currently requires pypdf2 for execution.
If I want to run it on another device I would have to install python3, pip and pypdf2.

Is there a way to include pypdf2 into my script so that I only need python itself to run my script?

EDIT:
The script runs on windows (10)

Comment: What is your target platform? A Windows system, Linux desktop/server? Is docker an option?

Comment: It's windows. I added it to the description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to distribute your script you can do this using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) as a stand-alone application.
This is a python module that bundles the interpreter with all the required libraries.